# The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri'

Tags: azure, next.js, auth0

I am trying to use Nextjs with Auth0 and I get the error

```
invalid_request: The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not valid. The expected value is a URI which matches a redirect URI registered for this client application.
```

I have the following code:

```
// pages/api/auth/[auth0].js
import { handleAuth } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';

export default handleAuth();
```

And I have the following in the auth0 dashboard

Allowed Callback URLS:

```
http://name.com/api/auth/callback, http://name.com/login/callback
```

and in the Azure redirect URIs single page application

```
http://name.com/api/auth/callback, http://name.com/login/callback
```

Can someone guide on what is wrong?